# Sending Multiple Serial Bytes from Arduino to Python to Display Images

Tags: python, serialization, arduino, raspberry-pi, jpeg

Essentially, I've been trying to write a program that when you push a specific button, a specific image appears. For example, if I push Button1, Image1 will be displayed. Next, if I push Button2, Image1 will disappear and Image2 will displayed. The problem I ran into is regarding button2. Eventually, I would like it so that many image files can be opened. Right now, I have serial data being sent from the arduino to a raspberry pi with python. The python program recognizes button1 being pressed and displays the image. However, when I press button2 (before or after pressing button1), the program stops and an error message appears.
Any help to resolve this issue would be great!

I have tried altering the bytes sent from the Arduino but it was to no avail. I am new to serial data processing so there could be something I have missed.

Arduino Code

```
int First=2;
int buttonState=0;
int Second=3;
int buttonState2=0;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(First, INPUT); 
 pinMode(Second, INPUT); 
}

void loop()
{
 int buttonState=digitalRead(First);
 int buttonState2=digitalRead(Second);

 if(buttonState==HIGH)
 {
   Serial.print(0x0);
   delay(100);
 }
 if (buttonState==LOW)
 {
   //do nothing
 }

  //BUTTON STATE SECOND
 if(buttonState2==HIGH)
 {
   Serial.print(0x1);
   delay(100);
 }
 if (buttonState2==LOW)
 {
 //do nothing
 }
}
```

Python Code(The formatting for two lines is off due to how the question is posted):

```
import numpy
import cv2, glob
import sys
import os
import serial
from subprocess import Popen

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)

Title = cv2.imread('/home/pi/Desktop/Avengers/Title.jpg')
Zero = cv2.imread('/home/pi/Desktop/Avengers/000.jpg')
while True:
    command = ser.read()
    if command:
        #flush serial for unprocessed data
        ser.flushInput()
        print("new command:", command)
        if (int(command) == 0):
            cv2.namedWindow("Title", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)          
cv2.setWindowProperty("Title",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
            cv2.imshow('Title', Title)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        if (int(command) == 1):
            cv2.namedWindow("Zero", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)          
 cv2.setWindowProperty("Zero",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
            cv2.imshow('Zero', Zero)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expect one image to displayed when I push a button, and another image to be displayed when I push the other button. The results of the code allow one button to display an image. However, when the other button is pushed, no image is displayed. In short, one button works and the other doesn't. An error message reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 490, in    read
    'device reports readiness to read but returned no data '
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but     returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/OpenJPG.py", line 14, in <module>
    command = ser.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 497, in read
    raise SerialException('read failed: {}'.format(e))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: read failed: device reports readiness to     read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

Comment: See what's happening when you send a '1' at button 1, and a '0' at button 2 (to tackle possible problems with the buttons). Or even better, just send the value without the buttons. Also, try sending an '1' instead of 0x01. If you intend to send hexadecimal values, use Serial.write instead.